# TypeError: t is not a function - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
{
 import React from "react";
import { Menu } from "antd";
import { HomeOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { SetLanguage } from "react-switch-lang";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import CookieRule from "./CookieRule";

const { SubMenu } = Menu;

const langmenu = (
  <Menu>
    <Menu.Item key="1">EN</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item key="2">RU</Menu.Item>
  </Menu>
);

class Navbar extends React.Component {
  state = {
    current: "home",
  };

  handleClick = (e) => {
    this.setState({ current: e.key });
  };


  render() {
    const { current } = this.state;
    const { t } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="navbar">
        <Menu
          onClick={this.handleClick}
          selectedKeys={[current]}
          mode="horizontal"
        >
          <Menu.Item key="main" icon={<HomeOutlined />}>
            <Link to="/">{t("menu.main")}</Link>
            Home
          </Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="leaderboard">Leaderboard</Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="about">About</Menu.Item>
        </Menu>
        <div className="navbar__logo">
          <span>CS</span>
          <span>TV</span>
        </div>
        <Menu
          onClick={this.handleClick}
          selectedKeys={[current]}
          mode="horizontal" 
          className="right-menu"
        >
          <Menu.Item key="favorites"> Favorites</Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="distribution"> Distribution</Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="overlay"> OBS overlay</Menu.Item>
        </Menu>
        <div className="navbar_lang">
          <SetLanguage />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Navbar.propTypes = {
  t: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};


export default Navbar;

}
```

I'm getting an error: `t is not a function`

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
> it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Navbar`.

Comment: How are you using the `Navbar` component? are you passing in a function for the `t` prop?

Comment: https://github.com/Satel14/react-tracker you can see here

Comment: In App.js you're using `<Navbar />` but not passing `t` prop through, so you'll get an error as it will be `undefined`, so trying to use `undefined` as a function will throw an error

Comment: can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: I can't since I didn't write this code and don't know what the `t` function is supposed to do. If you wrote this code you should know what it does. If you didn't write this code, then you can go back to the source of where you got it from and it should be documented there